# I was learning django and I dont understand what's happening here, what is the logic

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, textutils

```
 if removepunc == "on":
    punctuations = '''!()-[]{};:'"\,<>./?@#$%^&*_~'''
    analyzed = ""
    for char in djtext:
        if char not in punctuations:
            analyzed = analyzed + char
    params = {'purpose':'Removed Punctuations', 'analyzed_text': analyzed}
    return render(request, 'analyze.html', params)

else:
    return HttpResponse("Error")
```

So basically this removes punctuations from a sentence and I'm not getting the loop part of the program. If anyone could explain, it would be great! Thanks

Comment: My advice is to learn Python's basics before trying Django. If you don't know how a basic loop works in a language, you'll be wasting your time with an advanced web framework. Learning the basics will take two-three days but it will save a lot of time going forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have djtext string which you scroll on with the for: `for char in djtext`

for example, if djtext='abc' then with for loop on it, char is 'a' in the first loop after 'b' after 'c'.

in this line `if char not in punctuations`, is checked that if char not into punctuations till concatenate char with analyzed string.

in the end:

```
    params = {'purpose':'Removed Punctuations', 'analyzed_text': analyzed}
    return render(request, 'analyze.html', params)
```

response data is getting ready then data that is params with analyze.html file return and render from django view.